# Failed to import metagraph while loading frozen inference graph for tensorrt optimization

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt

I am trying to optimize my trained frozen inference graph using tensorrt.

https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/dgx/integrate-tf-trt/index.html#using-savedmodel

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as tf_graph:                                                  
    with tf.Session() as tf_sess:
        with tf.gfile.GFile(path, 'rb') as f:                           
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        infer_graph=  trt.create_inference_graph(
                                              graph_def,                                                                                                                        
                                              outputs=outputs_,
                                              is_dynamic_op=False,
                                     max_workspace_size_bytes=1<<30,
                                               precision_mode='FP16')

Error:

->  362    transformed_graph_def = tf_optimizer.OptimizeGraph(session_config_with_trt, grappler_meta_graph_def, graph_id=b"tf_graph")

/home/dell/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/grappler/tf_optimizer.pyc in 

-> 41 tf_opt.TF_OptimizeGraph(cluster.tf_cluster,config_proto.SerializeToString(),metagraph.SerializeToString(),verbose, graph_id, status)


/home/dell/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.pyc in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)

--> 528  
c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))

529
# Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive

530
# as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: Failed to import metagraph, check error log for more info.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wager the fetch nodes are not found inside the graph definition. From the TensorFlow logs (not talking about the traceback included in your question), you may read a line to the effect of:

```
E tensorflow/core/grappler/grappler_item_builder.cc:631] Fetch node <outputs_> doesn't exist in graph
```

You can fix the issue by correcting the name of the output nodes (the `outputs_` variable).

Inspecting the graph with TensorBoard can be helpful in finding the correct node names if you are not the author of the neural network.